# How do I use JavaScript to add a function that calls another function onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, onkeyup

So basically I have a little website that acts like a drum-kit. I want it to play sound when you click an on screen element and then I also want the same on screen elements to be able to be "clicked"" whenever I press the corresponding number-pad key.

I got it to play when i click on it, I just cannot get the onkeyup function to work.

```
  const sounds = document.querySelectorAll('.sound');
  const drumPads = document.querySelectorAll('.drumpadContainer');
  const keycodes =[
    49,
    50,
    51,
    52,
    53,
    54
  ]

  //Can i make sound??

  drumPads.forEach((drumpad, index) => {
    drumpad.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log("You clicked a button");
      sounds[index].currentTime = 0;
      sounds[index].play();
    })
    drumpad.addEventListener('onkeyup', function() {
      if (onkeyup == keycodes[index]){
        drumPads[index].click();
      }
    })

  });



})
```

Comment: The name of the event is just `keyup`, not `onkeyup`. But they're not typing on the `drumpad` element.

Comment: So, if I am understanding correctly, to get this to preform correctly I would want to do a window.eventlistener ? and then ask if event.keyup == keycodes[index]?
Sorry, I am very new :/

Comment: Read my answer to understand correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `keyup` handler should be on `window`. It should get the index of the key code, then use that to get the index of the corresponding element to click.

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    var index = keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode);
    if (index > -1) {
        drumPads[index].click();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what  needed. Thank you  so much, also by the way there is a small typo in your answer.

 `drumpads[index].click();`

should be:
`drumPads[index].click();`